# Join many xml documents to generate a new xml document using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio, linq-to-xml

I have to join many xml files in various folders to form one single xml file.
Example as below.

Based on `Displayid` and `Viewid`, we should be able to locate where to add the nodes in combining xml.

I'm able to retrieve files by folder path using directories but am unable to decide how to add nodes to other xml file.

First XML:

```
<root>
    <Display>
        <Displayid>0</Displayid>
        <view>
            <viewid>abc</viewid>
            <Screen>
                <ScreenId>abcd</ScreenId>
            </screen>
        </view>
    </Display>
</root>
```

Second XML

```
<root>
    <Display>
        <Displayid>0</Displayid>
        <view>
            <viewid>def</Viewid>
            <Screen>
                <ScreenId>abcd</ScreenId>
            </screen>
        </view>
    </Display>
</root>
```

Third XML:

```
<root>
    <Display>
        <Displayid>1</Displayid>
        <view>
            <viewid>efgh</viewid>
            <Screen>
                <ScreenId>ijklm</ScreenId>
            </screen>
        </view>
    </Display>
</root>
```

Result

```
<root>
    <Display>
        <Displayid>0</Displayid>
        <view>
            <viewid>abc</viewid>
            <Screen>
                <ScreenId>abcd</ScreenId>
            </screen>
        </view>
        <view>
            <viewid>def</viewid>
            <Screen>
                <ScreenId>abcd</ScreenId>
            </screen>
        </view>
    </Display>
    <Display>
        <Displayid>1</Displayid>
        <view>
            <viewid>efgh</viewid>
            <Screen>
                <ScreenId>ijklm</ScreenId>
            </screen>
        </view>
    </Display>
</root>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the tag "<Screen>" ends with "<screen>"? Also the "<Displayid>0<displayid>" in first xml. I see a case sensitive issue there

Comment: Also I am not sure where you are using the third XML? I don't see that see that in result?

Comment: I have updated my xml and result for more accurate understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Create an xsd for your final/output xml.
2. Iterate through all your xml files which you want to join and then deserialize each file into the object and store it into a collection.
3. Again, iterate through the collection which you got in the previous step and write a LINQ expression to map the Displayid and Viewid.
4. Serialize the final object to generate the target xml.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know what is the value for displayId then you could use Linq to XML to achieve the functionality, something similar to below code (Here I am taking the displayId as `0` mentioned in your input and output specification)-

```
            var xml1 = XDocument.Load("1.xml");
            var xml2 = XDocument.Load("2.xml");
            var xml3 = XDocument.Load("3.xml");

            var displayId = xml1.Descendants("Display").Descendants("Displayid").Where(a => a.Value == "0").FirstOrDefault().Value;           

            if (displayId == "0")
            {
                xml1.Descendants("view").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(xml2.Descendants("view"));

            }
            xml1.Descendants("Display").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(xml3.Descendants("Display"));
            xml1.Save("4.xml");
```

Please go through [Linq to XML here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-xml-trees) and about the Namespace details [here -](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2)

There are couple of methods in the namespace which will guide you on how work with XML similar to AddAfterSelf.

Comment: What if the XML files are coming from for each loop and we have one file to load at one time and not sure of displayid and viewid which comes randomly from file loading

Comment: The "Descendants(<Node>)" will give you the node you want read. In the loop read the node you want and accordingly append to first file. You can also see the different methods in the reference provided which will guide you in manipulating the XML contents.